# return value of function inside mypromise.then

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, return-value, es6-promise

I'm trying to get the response from an async promise to .then run a function on that once it resolves to clean up the json response..

Then return that value to the promise .. then return the promise back to the function that calls it in the front end

(or maybe several one after the other, just a good clean pattern of some kind)

```
vimeo = function(album_id) {

    var url = '';
    url += 'https://api.vimeo.com/users/vimeouser123/albums/';
    url += album_id;
    url += '/videos?direction=asc&sort=date';
    url += '&fields=uri,name,description,pictures';

    var options = {     
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer abc123',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    var vimeocall = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function(err, response, body){

            if(true){resolve(body)};

        });
    });

    vimeocall.then(function(result) {
        return vimeo_clean_data(result);    
    });

    return vimeocall;
}
```

So the promise returns ok after the api call, the vimeo_clean_data(result); function runs fine and console.log's the cleaned code

I can get it to return to the main promise to the client side fine but it's the raw json response

How would I get it to return the clean json to the promise which in turn is returned or just get that data back to the front end function that calls it

(for reference it's a meteor js method calling it, it returns the promise and data fine just not the promise.then part)

Comment: It is impossible, your call to the vimeo mehtod should be able to use a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `vimeocall` you will want to return the return of your previous call `vimeocall.then`.

```
return vimeocall.then(function(result) {
    return vimeo_clean_data(result);    
});
```

When you call `.then` on a promise it will always return another promise that gets resolved with the return of the callback passed in (or rejected with any errors caught).

https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40

> then must return a promise [3.3].
>
> ```
> promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
> ```
>
> - If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value `x`, run the Promise Resolution Procedure `[[Resolve]](promise2, x)`.
> - If either `onFulfille`d or `onRejected` throws an exception `e`, `promise2` must be rejected with `e` as the reason.
> - If `onFulfilled` is not a function and `promise1` is fulfilled, `promise2` must be fulfilled with the same value as `promise1`.
> - If `onRejected` is not a function and `promise1` is rejected, `promise2` must be rejected with the same reason as `promise1`.

### Alternatively

You could just put the call to `vimeo_clean_data()` in the original promise callback:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function(err, response, body){

        if(err){
            //either handle the error here or:
            reject(err);
        else {
            resolve(vimeo_clean_data(body))
        };

    });
});
```

Splitting your code into multiple `then()` calls is mostly helpful when you need to make multiple async calls.  You can return a promise from one `then()` call and the next `then()` in the chain will be called with the result of the returned promise. (And don't forget to handle/propagate possible errors!)

Comment: Thanks so much / for a fast reply! .. I tried both of those at first and have just again now in case I had the syntax wrong 

It gives me .. "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'vimeo': SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

So it's not getting it in time / sequence or is not passing correctly, u means undefined right??

Has got to be something simple

Thanks for your time

I like the .then method it seems cleaner for when you need to say .then update a db value with the clean result or update a user profile after some processing

Comment: It looks like the error is being thrown by your `vimeo_clean_data` function.  You can try console logging `body` before passing it in. If it is `undefined` then there is probably something wrong with your request options, otherwise you will want to look into your `vimeo_clean_data` function.

Comment: I tried that before as well, the response and body are ok, it outputs the correct code in the console server side for the cleaned code so it's passing the data to that function fine every time and it fires and outputs (on the server console) it just refuses to return back to the client?? Thanks again

Comment: @dominic-lane If meteor is not passing the data down to the client, you may want to open another question for that.   Make sure inside the method you are returning the promise from the vimeo function: `return vimeo(album_id)` meteor will wait for the promise to resolve and then use the resovled value.  https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-and-async-await-in-meteor-8f6f4a04f998

Comment: Thanks again, It's really odd.. it's calling the api fine, returning data fine, it returns the initial promise data to the client side ok, it's passing the api call data to the clean data function and outputting that server side fine, it just wont return that last part so it's all half working. I had tried what you suggested before as well (which thanks btw!) it just refuses to send the last part of the chain back to the client, it only sends the non-cleaned json. Maybe will just have to make a client side clean data function as is non sensitive and 'plug' it that way

Comment: @dominic Did you get this figured out?  I didn't see this comment until now.  If not, what does the code look like when you try it this way?

Comment: Thanks for checking up! v kind, in the end it was to do with the formatting of the json I was using (how typical but annoying!) Thank you for your help though, I was new to promises at the time (still am really) so was good to know I was going in the right direction. Kind thanks certainly!